# Calculate sensitivities of differential algebraic equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I would like to calculate sensitivities for a DAE. The DAE can be solved in Mathematica by:

```
fϵ[t_]:= 0; α = 0.5; k0 = 1; ρ = 1; γ = 1; γ1 = 0.1;
γ2 = 0.05; γ3 = 0.001; ζ  = 1; i0 = 0; θ0 = 0; 

sol = ParametricNDSolve[
    {θ'[t] == k0 (1 - θ[t]) Exp[(1 - α) (ϵr[t] - ϵ0)] - θ[t] Exp[-α (ϵr[t] - ϵ0)], 
     i[t] == γ (1 + γ1 ϵr[t] + γ2 ϵr[t]^2 + γ3 ϵr[t]^3) ϵr'[t] + ζ θ'[t], 
     ϵr[t] == fϵ[t] - ρ i[t], i[0] == i0, θ[0] == θ0}, 
    i, {t, 0, 10}, ϵ0]
```

Then, I can plot how the solution varies as a function of $\epsilon_0$:

[image]

When I try to look at sensitivities, however, with respect to this parameter, I seem to come awry (for example, here I am trying to determine sensitivities at $\epsilon_0=2$):

```
dide0 = i'[2] /. sol;
```

This plotted looks like the below:

[image]

whose scale isn't the true sensitivity.

Any ideas?

Comment: I could not run the code provided in the question, so I reformatted it.  Please check that I did not introduce errors.  In addition, please provide the values of constants and anything else that may be missing.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks! I have checked your version and all works ok. I have also added the parameter values. Any ideas on why these sensitivities look awry would be really appreciated!

Comment: You should include what Mathematica code you used to create the plots.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either of your figures. What code did you use? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is more an extended comment than a formal answer.  With the code and parameters given in the question, the first plot in the question should be something like

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[(i[k] /. sol)[t], {k, 1.5, 2.5, 0.2}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {t, i}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

The maximum of the curve decreases from 0.095 to 0.045 as `ϵ0` increases from 1.5 to 2.5, suggesting a sensitivity of the result to `ϵ0` of about -0.05 in the vicinity of `ϵ0 = 2`.  The sensitivity, `i'[2]`, computed directly, is

```
Plot[(i'[2] /. sol)[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {t, i'[2]}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

or about the same.  Perhaps, the plots in the question are for different parameters than those given in the question.